# Visual Studio 2022 .Net6 project build errors due to 'missing' references'

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded my solution, and projects to use .Net 6, and switched to using Visual Studio 2022. Since the upgrade, I'm unable to get certain projects to build.

I have compiler errors for missing references, even though the packages appear to be included...

[image: Compiler errors][image]Other team members can build the branch/code in its current state with Visual Studio 2022, so appears to be a Visual Studio configuration issue on my machine.

I've tried removing, and adding the packages via nuget, cleaning and rebuilding the project. I can't understand why they are not being picked up when the project builds.

Deleted .vs folder from the root of my solution.

Also tried removing the ComponentModelCache folder from...

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_998cb6a9`

*UPDATE*

I've added a further reference to the project via nuget for  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.

Hear is the contents of the project file, with packages referenced...

[image]

Still getting the same build errors. Asked another dev to check out the branch, and build with VS2022 and they were able to.

Comment: Hmm... Can you unload the csproj and copy and paste its contents into this question?

Comment: When you say `Other team members can build the branch/code in its current state...`, do you mean one teammate or more than one? Critical question because maybe the person who committed the code didn't commit all of the code assets.

Comment: Are you not missing a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` ?

Comment: Master of the Obvious: Did you install the .NET 6 framework on your developer machine?

Comment: @JimG. Yes, .Net 6 is installed. Can see the folder located in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201.

Comment: Can you please add output of `dotnet --list-sdks` and `dotnet --list-runtimes`? Also which VS workloads have you installed? Also check if there is [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file in the solution. Also try rebooting and checking out into a new folder/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help/pointers everyone. The cause seems to be Visual Studio was using cached nuget packages when restoring. The solution to this issue seems to be clearing all locally cached nuget packages with the command `dotnet nuget locals --clear all`

[image: command to clear local nuget folders]

More info can be found here...

[Clear local nuget folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

Once local/cached packages were cleared, a rebuild of the solution forced a full restore of all nuget packages. The packages were downloaded again, rather than using cached values. The solution finally built!

Hope this helps someone in the future, as I wasted an afternoon of trying to work out what the issue was.